# Sitecore 7.2 Content Editor: Long loading time when clicking on an item

Tags: sitecore, content-editor

Suddenly when I click on an item of a specific template, I get a loading time of minute until the item is loaded. This only happens for items based on this specific template. All other items based on other templates load fine and quick.

I found out that the same loading time happens when I click on the standard values of the template. Deleting the standard values didn't solve this.

Strangely this only happens on the staging system, not on my dev system.

In the Firefox network analysis I found this entry, that takes so long to load:

```
http://sc_instance/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Editor.aspx?ic=People/16x16/cubes_blue.png&he=Content Editor&cl=0
```

Any idea what might be the cause for this?

Answer (score 1):

This might look like it is related to the corrupt sitecore template item. Have you tried to,

re create the same template and create a new item using that template and see how it works ?

If it works normally than your template item is corrupted. Also check sitecore log files and there you will find more information related to this issue .

Thanks,

Hiral

Comment: There's nothing about this in the log files. I already deleted the template once and reinstalled it from my working dev instance, resulting in the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the long loading times when clicking on an item based on the specific template. In the template there is a multilist field with a query over a folder and subfolders in its source field, that gets all items based on a template ID to be shown in the multilist field. Once I got rid of the subfolders and changed the query to a simple /sitecore/content/... call the loading times got normal again.

What is strange is that the query in the source field didn't cause this for months.